# Random shuffle multiple lists python

Tags: python, list, random

I have a set of lists in Python and I want to shuffle both of them but switching elements in same positions in both lists like

```
          a=[11 22 33 44] b = [66 77 88 99]
          *do some shuffeling like [1 3 0 2]* 
          a=[22 44 11 33] b = [77 99 66 88]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is! You could generate random numbers between 0 and the length of the longest and move the elements. But what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that uses list comprehensions:

```
>>> a = [11, 22, 33, 44]
>>> b = [66, 77, 88, 99]
>>> p = [1, 3, 0, 2]
>>>
>>> [a[i] for i in p]
[22, 44, 11, 33]
>>>
>>> [b[i] for i in p]
[77, 99, 66, 88]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` in concert with the `random.shuffle` operator:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]          # list 1
b = ['a','b','c','d']  # list 2
c = zip(a,b)           # zip them together
random.shuffle(c)      # shuffle in place
c = zip(*c)            # 'unzip' them
a = c[0]
b = c[1]
print a                # (3, 4, 2, 1)
print b                # ('c', 'd', 'b', 'a')
```

If you want to retain a,b as lists, then just use `a=list(c[0])`.   If you don't want them to overwrite the original a/b then rename like `a1=c[0]`.

Comment: This doesn't work with python3: `TypeError: object of type 'zip' has no len()`

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon Tom's answer, you can make the p list easily and randomize it like this:

```
import random    
p = [x for x in range(len(a))]
random.shuffle(p)
```

This works for any size lists, but I'm assuming from your example that they're all equal in size.

Tom's answer:

> Here's a solution that uses list comprehensions:
>
> a = [11, 22, 33, 44]
> b = [66, 77, 88, 99]
> p = [1, 3, 0, 2]
>
> [a[i] for i in p]
>
> [22, 44, 11, 33]
>
> [b[i] for i in p]
>
> [77, 99, 66, 88]

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[11,22,33,44]
order = [1,0,3,2]                     #give the order
new_a = [a[k] for k in order]    #list comprehension that's it
```

You just give the order and then do list comprehension to get new list